# getopt -> return PHP Notice: Undefined index:

Tags: php, getopt

I'm using *getopt* to pass variables to my script, but I get the message:

> PHP Notice: Undefined index:

Here's my code:

```
$MyOptions = getopt("c:hp:");
if ($MyOptions['c']) { //line wher error show up!
    $MyClub = $MyOptions['c'];
} else {
    $MyClub = '53';
}
```

What did I miss?

Comment: Debug your own code. Use [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) to inspect variables.

Comment: I cannot use this. I have no CLI to see the output.

Comment: Errrrmm... wat?

Comment: Besides the fact that you somehow "don't have a CLI" whatever that means. Did you check the documentation of the functions you are using?

Comment: Yes sir, I did. "http://php.net/manual/de/function.getopt.php"

Comment: I developed the script on a Synology box. Here I could access through SSH or telnet and run the script on a CLI (Command Line Interface). I checked the variables and array as I was building the script. The error never showed up!   Now I have transferred the script on a web server hosted by a company and I only have a web interface, no SSH. Here I get the errors...

Comment: How do you run/execute this script? `getopt` is used to read command line argument and `command line` is a `CLI`.

Comment: I have an interface, where I browse for the file and it allows also on a second field to add options. The script should allow also no options, as in this case... here is what I get back from the schduler:"/opt/plesk/php/7.0/bin/php -f 'scripts/bin/import_fltt.php' > /dev/null"

Comment: Hello.. I managed to get the output when I define in the scheduler to report all messages. The array is empty if I don't pass any argument, so I should first check if the array exists before checking for any member of that array? Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the index `c` in your `$MyOptions` array does not exist, you can avoid this in a number of ways, but my preferred option in this case would be to replace the entire `if`-`else` statement with;

```
$MyClub = $MyOptions['c'] ?? '53';
```

The `??` is the [Null Coalescing operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php).

> The null coalescing operator (`??`) has been added as syntactic sugar for the common case of needing to use a ternary in conjunction with `isset()`. It returns its first operand if it exists and is not `NULL`; otherwise it returns its second operand.

Please be aware this is only available from PHP 7, otherwise you will have to use an `isset()` to check if the index exists.

Comment: Hi @LaurentZotto , if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @LaurentZotto Yep.